# Rhino Mocks - Private Properties On Ctor Test

Tags: rhino-mocks, rhino

i have a very simple question , i'm new to rhino
this is my class:
i want to test the property with 
Expect.SetPropertyWithArgument

can anyone show me how, cuase i tried and its not working..

```
public class person
{    

    public string Name {get;private set;}

    public person(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of `Expect.SetPropertyWithArguments` is that a property is set on the *mocked* object, not on the object under test. I'd also point out that the code you've shown doesn't set a property at all - it's setting a *field*.

Comment: See http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2008/10/09/rhino-mocks-3.5-gems-explicit-property-setting-expectations.aspx but I suspect you don't want to be using it in the first place. Are you really trying to test that a *dependency* property is set? Because that's what the method is for.